# Воспроизведение системных звуков

Tags: wpf, c#

Подскажите, возможно ли в wfp приложении проигрывать системные звуки?

Я хочу реализовать следующее: при определенном событии появляется отображается предупреждение и проигрывается системный звук "Windows Notify".

Comment: Перейдите, пожалуйста, по следущей ссылке: [генерация звука в WPF-приложениях](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/ee309883.aspx). Должно быть в точку (я так думаю).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно возможно. Только набор звуков не очень то велик:

```
 System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
 System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
 System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
 System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
 System.Media.SystemSounds.Question.Play();
```

Для проигрывания каких либо других звуков(только WAWE)используй:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer
```

Comment: Еще меня интересует такой вопрос, предупреждения - это стандартный MessageBox?

Comment: Да, именно он.

Comment: Ну тогда все проще. Просмотрев все перегрузки метода MessageBox.Show() все будет намного проще. Вот пример:
 MessageBox.Show("Неверный ввод доменного имени","Ошибка ввода",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
Ну так вот, в зависимости от MessageBoxImage проигрывается системный звук. Тут все достаточно просто.

Comment: Спасибо, отличный способ!